# Typescript generic object - append properties in return

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to take an object with optional properties and under certain circumstances, guarantee they will be there. For an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
interface PermissionsAvailable {
    [key: string]: {
        role?: number;
        feature?: string;
        has?: boolean;
    }
}

export function verifyPermissions<T extends PermissionsAvailable>(p: T): T & { [key: string]: { has: boolean }} {
    for (let i in p) {
        p[i].has = true;
    }

    return p as T & { [key: string]: { has: boolean }};
}

const r = verifyPermissions({prop1: {role: 2}});

if (r.prop1.has) {
    console.log("HAS PERMISSION!");
}
```

It's a little tricky, but in the end my goal is to have an object of 'permissions' and their requirements, and get back the same object with a boolean of whether or not it has that permission after running it through a function.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
[Link on TS playground with the problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20PermissionsAvailable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20role%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20feature%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20has%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20verifyPermissions%3CT%20extends%20PermissionsAvailable%3E(p%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%26%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20has%3A%20boolean%20%7D%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20i%20in%20p)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p%5Bi%5D.has%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20p%20as%20T%20%26%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20has%3A%20boolean%20%7D%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20r%20%3D%20verifyPermissions(%7Bprop1%3A%20%7Brole%3A%202%7D%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(r.prop1.has)%20%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(%22HAS%20PERMISSION!%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. You're iterating over `p` and for every item setting `has = true`, but that's pretty obvious since it's there. Who gets `has = false`?

Comment: It's just an example. What I really want to do is be able to pass in an object (T) that has properties role/feature/whatever, that is then read by the function, which returns the same keys from T but has the property has:boolean as the return value

Comment: Ok, and what's the problem? What's not working?

Comment: What I posted doesn't allow for type completion (T & {T: {has: boolean}} isn't valid). I want p.prop1.has to be type safe, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to do it using generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right then I think it should be:

```
function test<T extends PermissionSackProps>(p: T): T & { [key: string]: { has: boolean }} {
    for (let i in p) {
        p[i].has = true;
    }

    return p as T & { [key: string]: { has: boolean } };
}
```

`T & { T: { has: boolean } }` doesn't make sense as the indexes are the same, not of type `T`.

---

#### Edit

If you'll read the [Indexable Types docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) you'll notice that you need to access items in your object using brackets and not dot.

In your [code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20PermissionsAvailable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20role%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20feature%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20has%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20verifyPermissions%3CT%20extends%20PermissionsAvailable%3E(p%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%26%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20has%3A%20boolean%20%7D%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20i%20in%20p)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p%5Bi%5D.has%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20p%20as%20T%20%26%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20has%3A%20boolean%20%7D%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20r%20%3D%20verifyPermissions(%7Bprop1%3A%20%7Brole%3A%202%7D%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(r.prop1.has)%20%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(%22HAS%20PERMISSION!%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D) you have two problems because of that:

```
if (r.prop1.has) {
    console.log("HAS PERMISSION!");
}
```

should be

```
if (r["prop1"].has) {
    console.log("HAS PERMISSION!");
}
```

And

```
const r = verifyPermissions({ prop1: { role: 2 } });
```

should be:

```
const r = verifyPermissions({ prop1: { role: 2 } } as PermissionsAvailable);
```

If you'll point your mouse at the `r` in playground (in your code) you'll see its' type:

```
const r: { [x: string]: { role: number; }; prop1: { role: number; }; } & { [key: string]: { has: boolean; }; }
```

that's why even:

```
if (r["prop1"].has) {
    console.log("HAS PERMISSION!");
}
```

will raise an error, but this won't:

```
if (r["prop2"].has) {
    console.log("HAS PERMISSION!");
}
```

The type of `r` in [my code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20PermissionsAvailable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20role%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20feature%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20has%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20verifyPermissions%3CT%20extends%20PermissionsAvailable%3E(p%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%26%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20has%3A%20boolean%20%7D%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20i%20in%20p)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p%5Bi%5D.has%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20p%20as%20T%20%26%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20has%3A%20boolean%20%7D%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20r%20%3D%20verifyPermissions(%7B%20prop1%3A%20%7B%20role%3A%202%20%7D%20%7D%20as%20PermissionsAvailable)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(r%5B%22prop1%22%5D.has)%20%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(%22HAS%20PERMISSION!%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) is:

```
const r: PermissionsAvailable & { [key: string]: { has: boolean; }; }
```

and then both `r["prop1"].has` and `r["prop2"].has` are fine.

([modified code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20PermissionsAvailable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20role%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20feature%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20has%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20verifyPermissions%3CT%20extends%20PermissionsAvailable%3E(p%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%26%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20has%3A%20boolean%20%7D%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20i%20in%20p)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p%5Bi%5D.has%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20p%20as%20T%20%26%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20has%3A%20boolean%20%7D%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20r%20%3D%20verifyPermissions(%7B%20prop1%3A%20%7B%20role%3A%202%20%7D%20%7D%20as%20PermissionsAvailable)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(r%5B%22prop1%22%5D.has)%20%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(%22HAS%20PERMISSION!%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A))

Comment: This is really close, but it still sees prop1 as just being T, not with a guaranteed 'has' property.

Comment: I edited my original question with a link on TS Playground with the problem laid out

Comment: Check my revised answer, and please edit your question and add the code in your playground so that it will be clear to future reads without the need to go to playground.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was hoping to be able to get autocomplete for the keys that I had originally passed into the function, but it doesn't seem like that will be possible.

Comment: Actually, without the ability to get type completion on the specific properties passed in, might as well remove the generic and just do :
`function verifyPermissions(p: PermissionsAvailable)`